# AlarmManager Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm making an app which uses an AlarmManager and a Broadcast Receiver to generate a notification everyday at 8:20 AM.

One issue which I'm facing is that every time I open the app after 8:20 AM, the notification is generated.

I guess this is because I have called the receiver in the `onCreate()` method.
Is there a way to make sure that the receiver is registered only once?

Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
 }

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm Raised",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent1,0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_18dp);
        builder.setContentTitle("Tracker");
        builder.setContentText("Turn on Gps");
        builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        builder.setLights(0x0000FF,3000,2000);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(56, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `setInexactRepeating` indicates that when should the AlarmManager start its task. So if you give it a time in past it will fire once immediately. You must check if the calendar.getTimeInMillis() is before now and add a day to it if so.

So you should simply change this part of your code

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

to this:

```
long timeToStart = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
if(System.currentTimeMillis() < timeToStart){
    timeToStart += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // one day
}
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToStart, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```